# Physical interpretation of transfer function in control theory

Tags: control-theory

I'm learning about transfer functions in control theory. I'm struggling to find a physical interpretation for the input and output of a transfer function, both of which may be complex numbers. In the time domain, the physical interpretation of the system solution is clear: the input is time and the output is a vector of physical state variables.

Is there a physical interpretation for the complex input and output of a transfer function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Fourier transform`*`, Laplace transforms bears very little practical or physical insight. Actually the only reason you learn partial fraction expansion in the undergrad courses is because of Laplace Transforms.

The original insight of taking the Laplace transforms was to solve differential equations much more efficiently and in a more humane manner. But this got stuck and we are using it extremely blindly. 80% of control engineering students learn it as **replace the number of dots with powers of s**. It is very ill-taught and frankly you need to know lots of mathematics to start this type of queries if you want to do justice. For example, you stop worrying about the domain of convergence, analytic continuation and many many interesting features of this transform just after you learn about the definitions. If we are interested in stable systems and if `s` is not defined on the left half plane how is it that we discuss negative real part poles etc. See it immediately gets confusing because of the terrible motivation of such concepts. It is the same problem with Dirac's delta function. It only makes sense under the integral sine but we keep on multiplying with time functions etc. as if it is a real function. Hence, things become pretty tricky if you are not exposed to these concepts.

Another shortcoming of such thinking is that it forces control engineers think in terms of artificial causalities that bears no value in the original system. Take a clamped mass-spring-damper system, the equations that govern the motion is:

$$
m\ddot x(t) + b\dot x(t) + kx(t) = F(t)
$$
now, if you follow the typical route, you get 
$$
\frac{X(s)}{F(s)} = \frac{1}{ms^2+bs+k}
$$

here you must think that because of force we obtained a position output and hence the causality is position due to force. But obviously there is no such thing, the position and the force satisfy the same differential equation **simultaneously**. There is no such thing as force comes in and creates displacement.

My suggestion is that you keep this transform as a tool for solving/modeling differential equations as systems. Also, laplace transforms (or other integral kernels) are a much richer elements of mathematics. Hence, one should not overload them with artificial physical meanings.

`*` Fourier Transforms at least give some (and emphasis on *some* towards *little*) understanding of the **steady state**(!) behavior when the input is assumed to be pure sine. They are by no means indicative if you have a problematic transient regime.

Comment: Actually both the Fourier and the Laplace transforms give a lot more "physical" insight into the nature of signals than you give credit. The transforms represent signals in the frequency domain, a representation that  often more useful and more practical than the time-domain description. The reason must be that systems in general have very different responses in different frequency ranges.

One clear example is light. We think of light in terms of colors and frequencies. Time-domain signals are almost never mentioned. Music may be an even better example.

Comment: @Pait They are all examples of Fourier transform, a kernel evaluated on the imaginary axis, did you even see my footnote `*`? There is no particular insight Laplace transform gives in that regard other than converting a differential relation into an algebraic one. And again no transients only steady state. So you cannot guess the behavior of your system other than the final state.

Comment: I saw the paragraph that claims that the Fourier transform gives little insight, and ignores that the Laplace is particularly useful for studying transients. Scholars of communications and controls would differ. What can I say? If you don't think you need the insight provided by the Fourier and the Laplace transforms, don't use them.

Comment: @Pait I'm one of those scholars. We are trying to stop teaching Laplace transform as a department. There is no insight about transients other than nonminimum phase and a few minor points. All these vanish in MIMO context and actually gets even worse numerically. We are not in 1950s. If you have a counterargument put it in your answer otherwise don't speculate.

Comment: Fascinating. I could not disagree more completely. Especially perhaps with the non minimum phase being a minor point.

Disagreement is healthier than boring conformity, where are the new ideas going to come from if we don't get rid of some old ones?

Can you tell me a little more about how the efforts are going, where, and when? I didn't find a googlable link in your profile.

Comment: @Pait We try to make Jan Willems' behavioral approach separated to bitesize chunks so that an undergrad can take it with a healthy dose of ss and tf). Again, laplace transforms are exceedingly difficult if you want to do justice. I don't buy control textbook way of teaching it. Not only they are superficial but also usually wrong (without an extensive discussion on analytic continuation and $L_p$f spaces). They confuse much more that what they intend to demonstrate and again for MIMO there is practically no insight plus there is no reliable tool. matlab converts all to ss behind the scenes.

Comment: I would be very interested in knowing more about the teaching experience you have. I certainly have my share of criticism against textbook ways of doing things, but mine seem to go in a different direction. @percusse

Comment: .@percusse I'm rereading your comments. Nonminimum phase behavior is one of the best examples of why transfer functions are useful. There are reams of papers developing theory that may never be relevant in practice, for reasons that would become readily apparent by considering classical frequency domain issues.

Comment: @Pait I have two examples that fundamentally confuse students each and every year: When they learn Laplace transform they also learn the domain of convergence such that $F(s)$ exists for $Re(s) > a$. Then they start seeing things like a system is stable if all roots are $Re(s)<0$. Smart ones immediately notice this and go bananas about it. We try to help but no avail. The current practice of Laplace transforms are fundamentally wrong in their current narrative and even worse to set things right requires graduate level of integral transforms. [ctd.]

Comment: An engineering course shouldn't pretend to be rigorous in math if it is not possible. Hence, we always say *these are all mathematically wrong arguments, therefore don't overload with physical intuiton*. The  second case where it causes is the MIMO transmission zeros, especially, a MIMO system can have a noncancelling poles and zeros at the same location and don't appear in the rational entries is a mindboggling issue to explain. The only way to go about it is state space formulation. Frequency domain techniques are of course useful if we don't overload them with importance that they undeserve

Comment: Finally, many of those so-called insights are wrong adoptions of practicioners (I'm one of them occasionally) and doesn't reflect anything about the actual physical system such as PM,GM being independent variables but they don't understand the interplay between them etc. The strong desire to think linearly makes things extremely difficult to **unlearn**.

Comment: But then, stability margins which encompass the phase and gain margins - which indeed don't make that much sense - come out of the Nyqvist diagram, and are a much harder sell if you need to go through the H-infinity machinery. And the question of how formal one has to be in order to use the math will never be decided to anyone's satisfaction, except perhaps in a case to case basis. So, I don't know without seeing a complete Laplace-avoiding course material or lecture notes, but until then we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Pait Exactly. I agree. But imagine a fluid dynamics course that shows a simplified version of Navier-Stokes that doesn't involve turbulence terms and claims that it is the governing equation around the equilibrium point and claims the math is sound. That would be horrendous right? That is pretty much what we are doing with Laplace transform. And again, we are not ditching Fourier transform or frequency domain, my arguments only go for Laplace transform and the air of rigor that does not bear any value as it is presented.

Comment: .@percusse It is dangerous to reason using metaphors, but I'd compare the use of Laplace transforms in controls without a previous study of complex analysis to using the Navier-Stokes without a proof of existence of solutions. Is there any engineering education paper describing the approach you prefer?

Comment: @Pait I usually convert [this narrative](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~jwillems/Articles/JournalArticles/2007.1.pdf) to a less formal and more pragmatic one. Then hopefully the students see that transfer functions are only another tool to solve the involved differentials but not a source of insight per se. Behaviors are not the holy grail anyways. I'm not saying this is the way to go. But this is at least general enough to show that state space transfer functions signal flows etc are all inside a one big universum of modeling.

Comment: I don't know. One of the fascinating insights in controls is that, in the presence of transport delay, no matter how small, a sufficiently large feedback gain will bring about instability. This can be understood by more than one path, but the classical one might be the most convenient. On the one hand this suggests that Laplace transforms carry some fundamental intuition; on the other it creates a baseline against which any other analysis method needs to be judged.

Answer (score 1):

They are the Laplace transforms of the time-domain input and output signals. In the frequency domain, the input and output signals are complex functions of a complex variable $s$. In the time domain they are real functions of a real variable $t$, different ways of representating the same signals.

It may be easier to think in terms of the Fourier transform, which is a generalization of the Fourier series to signals that are not necessarily periodic. There exist the sine series, the cosine series, and the complex exponential series, which is most convenient and leads to the complex Fourier transform. The Fourier transform represents a time-domain signal in terms of its frequency components. The transform is defined to be a function of a complex variable, to take advantage of the properties of the complex exponential. The transfer function relates the Fourier transforms of the input and the output.

The transfer function concept is the same, whether you use the Fourier or the Laplace transform. The latter is more practical in the study of control systems, because it takes care of initial conditions problems more easily, and is convenient in stability analysis.

The transfer function maps a complex function of the complex variable $s$ into another complex function - not a complex variable into another. The functions represent the input and the output in the frequency domain - as compared to the more usual representation of the input and output as functions of the time $t$.

Comment: I think the question is about how to interpret the complex character. For instance, suppose I fix $b \in \mathbb{R}$; what does the function $a \mapsto F(a+bi)$ tell me?

Comment: @Ian is exactly right. I'm trying to get some intuition about the physical meaning of the transfer function.

Comment: See expanded answer.

Comment: @Pait I still don't see the physical interpretation of the input and output of the transfer function. Is it just a mathematical tool that has no physical interpretation? If the transfer function maps $a + bi$ to $c + di$, what does that tell me about the physical dynamics of the system? How can I physically interpret these complex numbers?

Comment: The input and the output are not complex variables - they are complex functions, see above.

Comment: @Pait When I said input and output, I meant input and output of the transfer function. In other words, $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. In any case, I still don't see the physical interpretation. If I have a time domain solution $f$ of a system with one variable for height, and $f(5)=3$, then I can interpret this to mean that the height is 5 at time 3. If I have a system with transfer function $F$, what does it mean that $F(2+3i)=4+6i$?

Comment: These are not the usual meanings of input and output. I suppose you mean the complex argument and the corresponding value of the transfer function.

The magnitude of $F(s)$ for $s = j \omega$ (I am using $j = \sqrt{-1}$) is the magnitude of the $F(s)$ gain at frequency $\omega$. Likewise the phase is the phase shift of the output with respect to the input. This provides a fairly complete and intuitive understanding of the transfer function $F(s)$.

Comment: @Pait I'm still not sure how to physically interpret "the magnitude of the $F(s)$ gain at frequency $\omega$". Likewise, I'm not sure how to physically interpret the phase shift of the output with respect to the input. Time and space are intuitive to me. This means that if $f$ is the time domain solution, $f(5)=3$ has an easy, intuitive physical interpretation. Is it the case that the transfer function doesn't have an equally intuitive interpretation?

Comment: The gain is the ratio between the output and the input, in magnitude. The phase shift between two sinusoids of the same frequency $\sin (\omega t + \phi)$ and $\sin (\omega t)$ is $\phi$.